# Powershell Remoting: Execute local function on two target servers

Tags: powershell, remoting

I have a function foo on my local Machine. (In my profile, but calling c:\scripts\foo.ps1 would be also OK!)
How do i load this on ServerA and ServerB so i can execute the function in the next statement?

This is what i tried with no success..

```
$serverlist = 
"192.168.20.1",
"192.168.20.12"  
foreach ($item in $serverlist) {
    New-PSSession -ComputerName "$item" -Credential $cred -Name  ($item + "_session")
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $item -Credential $cred -filepath scripts:\foo.ps1 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $item -Credential $cred -scriptblock {foo}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes here:

1. First of all, `Invoke-Command` can use *either* the `-ComputerName` parameter *or* the `-Session` parameter. You are creating a session here but are not using it, therefore the commands run are executed in different sessions and don't know anything about each other.
2. `-ComputerName` takes a `string[]` so you could drop the `foreach`. You can then probably just put the function definition and the call in a single script block.